# Error: Unable to decode revert reason using getReverReason()

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js, ethers.js

I am trying to understand why an ethereum transaction reverted by using getReverReason() from eth-revert-reason. I first tried using [their example](https://github.com/authereum/eth-revert-reason) which is:

```
console.log(await getRevertReason('0x6ea1798a2d0d21db18d6e45ca00f230160b05f172f6022aa138a0b605831d740'))
```

but I get the error "await is only valid in async function". When I tried to run it inside the async function as below:

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
const ethers = require('ethers');
const getRevertReason = require('eth-revert-reason');
const txHash = '0x6ea1798a2d0d21db18d6e45ca00f230160b05f172f6022aa138a0b605831d740'

// Failed with revert reason "Failed test"
async function reason() {
    await getRevertReason(txHash)
}

console.log(reason())
```

I always get the same result, regardless of the Transaction Hash:

```
Error: Unable to decode revert reason.
```

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

The author has not been updated for two years. I have updated it on the basis of this project, but I have not considered other networks. If you have any questions, please ask me and I will update them immediately. (Please forgive me for not doing well, it is the first time to try to make a package) For details, see https://www.npmjs.com/package/revert-reason or https://github.com/LAMOUR0913/revert-reason.git;

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32940264)